# Magento2 : Override Category List page with No dependency on Other Custom Module

Tags: magento2.3, overrides, catalog, catalog-product

I want to override category.products.list to display 1 custom attribute value to each product in list.

and i know i can override product/list.phtml to my module and there i can customize code in loop to display that attribute value.

but in case tomorrow any other module override list.phtml then my changes are gone.

so is there any way, that any module override list.phtml my code to display custom attribute value to each product should appear?

Comment: You can override product/list.phtml in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin[enter link description here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) on `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\List::getTemplate()`.

> If you using after plugin on `getTemplate` then if anything
>   modification comes from Other 3rd party modules **using Layout** will
>   not be affected as template file location of Block finally comming
>   from this method.

## Plugin Class

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Magento\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product;

class ListProduct
{

    public function afterGetTemplate(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        if($subject->getNameInLayout() == 'category.products.list'){
            // StackExchange_Magento::product/list.phtml  is your template file 
            return "StackExchange_Magento::product/list.phtml";
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

## di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchange_Magento_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Block_Product_ListProduct" sortOrder="10" type="StackExchange\Magento\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"/>
    </type>
</config>
```